# Flash Based Audio Splitter Control

Tags: flash, audio, timeline, waveform, splitter

Does anyone know of an existing flash (swf) based audio control that is available (free or commercial) that provides a timeline waveform visualization with the ability to select and play a portion of the timeline?

For example, the flash control used by this website... http://www.makeownringtone.com/

It does exactly what I'm wanting to do.  I need this capability to allow a user to mark a section of an audio file which can then be synchronized with other visual elements on a web page using javascript.

It is important that the user be able to see the wave form of the audio because they can save time by visually guessing where certain sounds start and end in a file.  The user can then select this block of the audio and preview the sound and tweak the selection if need be.

Thanks!

Comment: Most of the various audio visualization flash applications actually use data generated server-side for this.  It can be cached this way as well.  Then you have to deal with synchronization issues, but if you have a constant-bitrate audio file, this isn't much of a problem.

Comment: I don't think you understand what Chris is asking Brad.... none of what hes asking about requires server side interaction at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Just uploaded an old bit of source code for when I made an attempt at building an online sound mixer. Can download it here:

http://code.google.com/p/ascensionsystems/downloads/list

All source in my google code page is MPL so feel free to use it in whatever way. Maybe it'll save you some time to chop some bits out of there and use it. :)

**Original Answer**
Here is a demo + source code of wave form + filters. "Bookmarking" a position on the sound just requires saving the SoundChannel.position property.

//Render waveform for entire sound
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=329

//Rendering dynamically + filters
http://www.anttikupila.com/flash/soundfx-out-of-the-box-audio-filters-with-actionscript-3/